# Function having an in parameter and returning a object type

Tags: oracle, plsql

**How can I pass number as in parameter and return a object type in a function**

```
create type my_details as 
object(v_ename varchar2(20),v_sal number(10));


create or replace function f_emp(v_empno in number)
  return my_details
as
  v_det my_details;
begin
  select ename,sal 
    into v_det.v_ename,v_det.v_sal 
    from emp 
   where empno=v_empno;
  return v_det;
 end;
```

When I try to call the function, I get an error

```
declare
  v_type my_details;
begin
  v_type:=f_emp(7839);
end;
/
```

The error stack

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.F_EMP", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Can any one help me pointing out where I have made mistake and how can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your function would either need to initialize the object before referencing it

```
create or replace function f_emp(v_empno in number)
  return my_details
as
  v_det my_details := new my_details(null, null);
begin
  select ename,sal 
    into v_det.v_ename,v_det.v_sal 
    from emp 
   where empno=v_empno;
  return v_det;
```

end;

or your could call the constructor as part of the `select`

```
create or replace function f_emp(v_empno in number)
  return my_details
as
  v_det my_details;
begin
  select my_details(ename,sal)
    into v_det 
    from emp 
   where empno=v_empno;
  return v_det;
```

end;

Putting the constructor in the `select` statement would be the approach I would generally suggest.